# Subquery Issue in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a project using Access 2007 but are struggling writing a simple subquery. I am trying to get results from a table of the next 6 occurrences after a certain ratio has been recorded.

I was hoping the following code would work in Access:

```
SELECT [runner name], [race ID], [race date], [placing], [class]
FROM runners
WHERE [runner name] IN
                 (SELECT [runner name] from 6F Full Form WHERE [ratio] >9       
ORDER BY [runner name], [race ID], [date], [placing], [class];
```

I receive the error message below.  NB `6F Full Form` is a query I have written and I'm trying to use this in the subquery.

> Syntax error in query expression '[runner name] IN (SELECT [runner name] from 6F Full Form WHERE [ratio] >9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current SQL code is that field/table/query names containing spaces or [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) must be enclosed with square brackets - hence

```
from 6F Full Form WHERE
```

Should be written:

```
from [6F Full Form] WHERE
```

---

You also have a potential typo in your `order by` clause:

```
SELECT ..., [race date], ...
...
ORDER BY ..., [date], ...;
                 ^--------------- Should this be [race date]?
```

---

It is worth adding that you could also achieve this using joins, e.g.:

```
select
    r.[runner name],
    r.[race id],
    r.[race date],
    r.[placing],
    r.[class]
from
    runners r inner join
    (select distinct f.[runner name] from [6f full form] f where f.[ratio] > 9) q 
    on r.[runner name] = q.[runner name]
order by
    r.[runner name],
    r.[race id],
    r.[race date],
    r.[placing],
    r.[class]
```

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac, that gave me what I was after.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 (SELECT [runner name] 
 FROM [6F Full Form] 
 WHERE [ratio] >9       
 ORDER BY [runner name], [race ID], [date], [placing], [class]);
```